# Format a corrupted SD card

Tags: sd-card

I was making a bootable SD card for my raspberry pi on ubuntu 18.04 and accidentally I put my computer to sleep. I ended up running my SD card, it doesn't want to format nether be partitioned, I tried using Gparted with no results: there is a red exclamation sign next to a EXT4 partition name. 
I event tried to use the command:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 -v /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

It displays this and get stuck:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2 has 4 heads and 16 sectors per track,
hidden sectors 0x18000;
logical sector size is 512,
using 0xf8 media descriptor, with 10452992 sectors;
drive number 0x80;
filesystem has 2 32-bit FATs and 8 sectors per cluster.
FAT size is 10192 sectors, and provides 1304072 clusters.
There are 32 reserved sectors.
Volume ID is 0538c1e1, no volume label.
```

Is there a way to fix my SD card ? 
Thank you for trying to help.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Can you access it with `cfdisk /dev/mmcblk0` (not the partition, the whole drive)?

Comment: I always use `dd` to write zeros to the first 100MB or so of any device (USB stick, SD card, HDD) that has a screwed up partition table. Then I reboot and use `gparted`.

Answer (score 2):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd* bs=512 count=32
```

The above should clear your partition table. Then you should be able to use `gparted`. Replace /dev/sd* with your device (not your partition. e.g: /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)

*NB: MAKE SURE YOU USE THE CORRECT DEVICE FOR `of=...` OR HORRIBLE THINGS WILL HAPPEN.*

Comment: +1 before I had to have root permission on my SD to make changes and now using that command with `root` privilages allowed the non-root user to make changes